# Excel: How to subtract the number of hours of a date such as "2022-07-18 17:40:02.878981+00:00" - "2022-07-18 17:03:41.638306+00:00"?

Tags: excel-formula

Before going any further, please note that I have very poor knowledge in Excel, and that 99.99% of the time I have to search on the internet to achieve the simplest things in Excel; although I have to use it for "simple" calculations.
Be assured that I have already gone through this and to many try and tests.

I have a table similar to this:

[image: Excel table containing date and time]

I want to subtract the values of "Discovery End Time" to the "Discovery Start Time" in a third column in order to find the duration of an action.

I do not care at all about the gibberish after yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in the calculation. It should not appear in the column duration.

I have tried many things, such as what is on [this page](https://www.exceldemy.com/subtract-date-and-time-in-excel/) but failed until now.

Any hints please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is all the extra information after `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000` which it the max accuracy of Excel.  So we just use the left 19 characters, since you do not care about the decimal seconds.

```
=LEFT(B2,19)-LEFT(A2,19)
```

This will probably return a double.  You will need to format the cell as desired: `[hh]:mm:ss`

Comment: Maybe better to format as `[hh]:mm:ss` in case the time goes over 24 hours.

Comment: ahh, you are correct, probably do not want the `yyyy-mm-dd` part at all.

Comment: Yes, just realised I included that with my suggestion.... not what I meant. :)